# mapping request.data into a onetoone field

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, one-to-one

I have a JSON request data as follows and I want to process that using Django serializer and views in order to create the record in the database using a POST request.

```
{
    "username":"user1",
    "first_name":"name1",
    "email":"name1@gmail.com",
    "phone": "123456",
    "app_id": "435673339303abc"

}
```

And following are my Django database models and serializer where a custom user model is created which has a onetoone django user model:

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models


class CustomUserModel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    app_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'email')


class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUserModel
        fields = ('user', 'phone', 'app_id')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        user = UserSerializer.create(UserSerializer(), validated_data=user_data)
        customuser, created = CustomUserModel.objects.update_or_create(user=user, defaults={
            'phone': validated_data.pop('phone'),
            'app_id': validated_data.pop('app_id')})
        return customuser
```

**views.py**

```
class usersApi(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = CustomUserSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = CustomUserModel.objects.all()
        return queryset

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = CustomUserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=ValueError):
            serializer.create(validated_data=request.data)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.error_messages,
                        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

But with this serializer and views, I have to pass a nested json data as follows with user object which I don't want to.

```
{
    "user":
    {
    "username":"user1",
    "first_name":"name1",
    "email":"name1@gmail.com"
    },
    "phone": "123456",
    "app_id": "435673339303abc"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several iterations, I found a way to do this by mapping request data into a dictionary.
**views.py**

```
class usersApi(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = CustomUserSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = CustomUserModel.objects.all()
        return queryset

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        username = request.data['username']
        first_name = request.data['first_name']
        email = request.data['email']
        phone = request.data['phone']
        app_id = request.data['app_id']

        user_data = {'user': {'username': username, 'first_name': first_name, 'email': email}, 'phone': phone,
                     'app_id': app_id}
        serializer = CustomUserSerializer(data=user_data)

        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=ValueError):
            serializer.create(validated_data=user_data)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.error_messages,
                        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the row from CustomUserModel in your view.
CustomUserModel.objects.get(user=request.user.user_id)

Comment: Can you please elaborate? There are no user_id field for Django builtin User model,  I suppose!

Comment: there must be a User Model and by user_id, i mean the primary key in the User Model

Comment: I modified views code in this way: 
`def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = CustomUserModel.objects.get(user=request.user.user_id)`

This is throwing error: `'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'user_id'`

I checked by printing request.POST in console. It gave me `<QueryDict: {}>`

Comment: Just fetch all the objects from User model for now and see whats the primary or unique key. use .all() to get all the rows .

Comment: sorry for my little knowledge in django. By default, `id` will be the primary key field for `User` model right? Can you describe the full code so that I can easily understand?

Comment: try CustomUserModel.objects.get(user=request.user.id)

Comment: getting error `CustomUserModel matching query does not exist.`